# How to filter DB table for each day of the month?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Using Postgres 13 I have a simple table `transactions`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.transactions (
    id int8 NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    start_time_local timestamptz NULL,
    end_time_local timestamptz NULL,
)
```

To get a list of all of transactions that have begun, but not yet ended on a given day I can run a query like

```sql
SELECT
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  TRANSACTIONS T
WHERE
  T.START_TIME_LOCAL::DATE <= '2022-07-25'
  AND T.END_TIME_LOCAL::DATE >= '2022-07-25';
```

However, I would like to get the results for every day in a given month, so that the results look like the following:

| open_transactions | date |
| --- | --- |
| 13 | 2022-08-01 |
| 18 | 2022-08-02 |
| 200 | 2022-08-03 |

How can I do this with a single query? I suspect a `group by` clause combined with some sort of sequence might be helpful, but I can't seem to figure it out. I tried something like the following, but it's not quite what I'm looking for as it doesn't group by the days the way I'm looking for:

```sql
WITH transaction_data
AS (
    SELECT count(*) AS transaction_count
        ,t.start_time_local::DATE AS start_day
        ,t.end_time_local::DATE AS end_day
    FROM transactions t
    WHERE t.start_time_local::DATE >= '2022-08-01'
        AND t.end_time_local::DATE <= '2022-08-31'
    GROUP BY start_day
        ,end_day
    ORDER BY start_day
    )
    ,days
AS (
    SELECT '2022-08-20'::DATE + sequential_dates.DATE AS DATE
    FROM generate_series(0, 9) AS sequential_dates(DATE)
    )
SELECT transaction_count
    ,start_day
FROM transaction_data
JOIN days ON days.DATE = start_day
GROUP BY days.DATE
    ,start_day
    ,transaction_count;
```

Comment: If you are casting it to date won't `"START_TIME_LOCAL::DATE <= '2022-07-25' AND END_TIME_LOCAL::DATE >= '2022-07-25';"` will give you the same result as just grouping by date? (`START_TIME_LOCAL::DATE  = '2022-07-25' `).

But you can just subtract `endtime - starttime` and based on that select all the open transactions

Answer (score 0):

Use this in select:

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('day',date_column) AS dayy, count(transaction_count)
```

and then in `GROUP BY dayy`

instead of 'day' you can use week, month, quarter, year variable

it will count every day

```
select DATE_TRUNC('day',start_day) AS dayy, count(transaction_count)
from(
SELECT transaction_count
    ,start_day
FROM transaction_data
JOIN days ON days.DATE = start_day
GROUP BY days.DATE
    ,start_day
    ,transaction_count)x
group by dayy
```